# If $T_{kl}=\epsilon_{kil}m_i$, how to show $m_i=0.5\epsilon_{ilk}T_{lk}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, magnetic-moment

In a book I am reading (about magnetic dipole), it is given that $T_{kl}=\epsilon_{kil}m_i$. Then, it says since $T_{kl}=-T_{lk}$, it can be shown that $m_i=0.5\epsilon_{ilk}T_{lk}$. I understand that $T_{kl}$ is antisymmetric, but how to show the subsequent result?

Comment: Contraction your equation with $\epsilon _{klj}$ and use formula for contraction of epislon with itself over two indices (something with a bunch of deltas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is the following. Multiply both side of the equation by $\epsilon_{jkl}$. Then use the identity $\epsilon_{jkl}\epsilon_{ikl}=2\delta_{ji}$.That will give you the desired identity.